# How to upload a file "Unassigned" to #Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

We have uploaded documents attached to a record (a case, an order, etc.) but now, we want to know if somebody can upload a file to Acumatica without attaching to a record. I see the option "Show Unassigned Files" in SM202520 but I have not been able to upload a file without attaching to a record.

Any clue to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Im going to venture that the answer is "no" but don't know for certain. You can however get to the same desired end result by generating a record for the specific purpose of holding documents that are unassignable to anything else. For example, you can have a Case or order titled "Unassigned documents" then treat anything there as unassigned. this strategy is contingent on there being no problems with having this sudo case|order record in place. If I hope this helps. Robert

Comment: Thanks for sharing with us your thoughts. We have decided to build something similar to your idea, instead of using a case we are using now a wiki page "Important Files to Attach in each transaction" to manage the files that are important for a company and should be attached in every transaction for this company. Thank you again!

Comment: @Clan, awesome! good to hear. If i do ever learn of a way to do it without a record ill follow up and let you know. good to know you have a workaround.